# geo node problem in blender 3.6.4 random node, when random value added it multiply the objects on many points, can anyone help me with it

Tags: random

[image: here is the image with destail i have marked with white pecil]

> Here is the image with details, I have marked it with white pencil. I want to know how to fix this issue.

Comment: please don't write in capital letters because this might be considered as rude and shouting. thx.

Comment: @Chris tell that to [CNN](https://dynaimage.cdn.cnn.com/cnn/c_fill,g_auto,w_1200,h_675,ar_16:9/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.cnn.com%2Fcnnnext%2Fdam%2Fassets%2F200322115530-sotu-panel-full-00040227.jpg) - I don't know why they do this, perhaps a huge team of advisors figured out it improves audience retention by 1%… While it indeed **can** be considered as rude and shouting, I think it's not important. The fact it's suboptimal and degrades readability is the reason why I'd recommend not to do so. Ironically, the title has no capital letter at all.

Answer (score 2):

your mesh to curve node makes no sense in your node tree. Delete that and it's ok.

The mesh to curve node creates multiple curves here and more than 9 points. You can verify this by extending your node tree like this and playing with the start value:

[image]

Comment: THANKS ALOT, DIDNT SEE THIS COMING

Comment: @ganeshjsuthar Please stop writing in capital letters.

Comment: @ganeshjsuthar: if my answer helped you, pls click on the checkmark left of my answer, thx